# merge php array by making key and values

Tags: php, arrays

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Member ID
        [1] => Name
        [2] => Age
        [3] => Relationship
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1001
        [1] => Swift
        [2] => 34
        [3] => Policy Holder
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5259
        [1] => John
        [2] => 31
        [3] => Son
    )
```

I have an array similar to above, I want to merge it in such a way that values in array index 0 becomes an array and has values as the value of other indexes something like

```
Member ID ('1001', '5259'),  
 Name ('Swift', 'John'), 
  Age ('34','31') and 
  Relationship ('Policy Holder','Son').
```

I have tried `array_merge` but couldn't get desired result, also `array_combine` had problems.

Comment: Please show your desired output.

Comment: Member ID ('1001', '5259'),  
 Name ('Swift', 'John'), 
  Age ('34','31') and 
  Relationship ('Policy Holder','Son'). I want this as output. Member ID, Name, Age and Relationship are array here.

Comment: array_merge or array_combine wont help you. you should try write some simple foreach loops and form your output. and then if you are struggling post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no read-to-use function for such specific task. Specific in the sense that the logic of *how* you process that set of data is arbitrary. So you have to somehow describe what to do with that data...

You have to create your own routine. Take a look at this simple example:

```
<?php
$output = [];
$input = [
    [
        'Member ID',
        'Name',
        'Age',
        'Relationship',
    ],
    [
        1001,
        'Swift',
        34,
        'Policy Holder',
    ],
    [
        5259,
        'John',
        31,
        'Son',
    ]
];

$keys = array_shift($input);
foreach ($input as $set) {
    foreach ($set as $index=>$value) {
        $output[$keys[$index]][] = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($output);
```

The output obviously is:

```
array(4) {
  'Member ID' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(1001)
    [1] =>
    int(5259)
  }
  'Name' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(5) "Swift"
    [1] =>
    string(4) "John"
  }
  'Age' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    int(34)
    [1] =>
    int(31)
  }
  'Relationship' =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(13) "Policy Holder"
    [1] =>
    string(3) "Son"
  }
}
```